# Python pygame writing text in sprite

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I am making a game where you shall shoot down diffrent boxes with diffrent nummber and text on and was wondring if you can write text as a sprite

Comment: Have you read the [docs on `pygame.font`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html)? It creates a `Surface`, just like `image` does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class Text(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, text, size, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor  
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
        self.textSurf = self.font.render(text, 1, color)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        W = self.textSurf.get_width()
        H = self.textSurf.get_height()
        self.image.blit(self.textSurf, [width/2 - W/2, height/2 - H/2])
```

I hope that helps, this will draw text centered on surface in a sprite

Comment: thx!!! I am very new on python and pygame and did't know that you could use other things than square and image in sprites. I made pictures of all the words and saved them as png files. Thx anyway!!!

Comment: That works, however it will take less space on the hard drive if you use drawing text within the program

Comment: I know im using your motode.

Comment: Do you know if you can set a image under the text in the same sprite?

Comment: Yeah just blit an image to `self.Surf` before you blit the text

Comment: is `self.Surf` the same as `self.image`?

Comment: yup it's just a surface. self.image is an instance of `pygame.Surfarce()` as is the `self.Surf` which means that they are interchangable, but you are right in the fact that self.image would probably be easier to use

Comment: what code can I use to blit a image to `self.Surf`?

Comment: self.Surf.blit(image, 0, 0)

Comment: When I try to run this, I get the error `TypeError: invalid destination position for blit` firing on this line: `self.Surf.blit(self.textSurf, width/2 - W/2, height/2 - H/2)`